# Connect to ubuntu port from docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking

I have a application running on port 8180 on my local machine
When I try to `wget http://192.168.1.12:8180/auth` from docker container,
I get following error

```
--2019-10-10 08:17:03--  http://192.168.1.12:8180/auth
Connecting to 192.168.1.12:8180... failed: Connection refused.
```

I tried following

```
❯ sudo ufw status                                                                                                                                        [14:17:44]
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8180/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8180/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Still getting the same error.

How to fix this??

Comment: why it's print local Docker gateway IP? `https://172.17.0.1:8180/auth`? also why there is **https** in error?

Comment: i tried with both local ip, docker ip and http and https

Comment: the port is invliad in the error `Connecting to 192.168.1.12:8180` it should be `8080`

Comment: that is just typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a network bridge in Docker. Provided that 192.168.1.12 is indeed your host's IP, this command will create a network 'dockernet'

```
$ docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --gateway 192.168.1.12 dockernet
```

Use this network when running the container:

```
$ docker run --net=dockernet [...]
```

Another approach would be to use 'host' network driver for the container, if you find the lack of network isolation acceptable for the purpose. See [Host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) and its [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) for more info.

In general, [Docker's network documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/) is a recommended and easy read.